# Google DNS is too slow connecting to Google APIs

Tags: domain-name-system, connection, google

I have a linux server in Germany. The server is configured with Google DNS. When I call from the server some Google API, the connection is too slow, it takes always 2 or 3 seconds to connect to the Google server. I have no problem connecting to other servers.
Paradoxically it seems there are problems resolving Google URLs with Google DNS.
I have temporarily resolved inserting a row in the file hosts.txt that associates the Google IP corresponding to the Google API that I use.
Can I resolve this problem in another (clean) way?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Google's public DNS servers where performance matters to you. Both they and the Level 3 servers (4.2.2.1, etc) are under heavy loads and will typically perform worse than a locally hosted resolver or even your ISP's resolvers.

Comment: Ok, but why there are problems only with requests to Google Server?

Comment: Who knows, but Google's public recursive resolvers certainly aren't their authoritative name servers, so they have to be resolved from 8.8.8.8 just like they would from any other name server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [namebench](https://code.google.com/p/namebench/) or [DNS Benchmark](https://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm) from GRC to do a test which DNS server is fastest from your location.

**I recommend you to use namebench** instead of GRC's DNS Benchmark because GRC is tailored to the US. namebench on the other hand will scan your regional's dns server and it is normally the fastest dns server to choose from.

I just tried it and the **namebench shows me how slow google dns servers are compared to my local dns servers** (which is a whopping **243% faster** than google!).

Here is a screenshot of my benchmark... (sorry had to censure the IPs due to company policy)..

[image: namebench dns benchmark result]

Here is the link to namebench: https://code.google.com/p/namebench/